# How to execute commands through PHP?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I am trying to convert videos into MP4 using FFMPEG. I have it set up this way:

```
.
.
private $ffmpegPath;

public function __construct($con) {
    $this->con = $con;
    $this->ffmpegPath = realpath("ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe");
}
.
.
public function convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath){
    $cmd = "$this->ffmpegPath -i $tempFilePath $finalFilePath 2>&1";

    $outputLog = array();
    exec($cmd, $outputLog, $returnCode);

    if($returnCode != 0){
        foreach ($outputLog as $line){
            echo $line."<br>";
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And in the browser i get the following error:
'C:\xampp\htdocs\Thinksmart First Sprint' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

In my constructor i have it set up to give me the realpath and i suspect that this is what it does in the command line:

C:/xampp/htdocs/Thinksmart FIrst Sprint/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i (file temp name) (file name i want)

And this should work, but i dont know why it wont. Any ideas? Its my first time working with video conversions.

Comment: when you have spaces in a path\directrory you need to quote it

Comment: @tim As far as I know, realpath() will return the root dir of the file. For example even if your file is on desktop it will say C:/users/username/desktop/filename
So in my case it will already have said C:/xampp/htdocs/Thinksmart First Sprint/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe but the ladder 3 parts do not appear in the string

Comment: Quote it: `$cmd = '"'.$this->ffmpegPath.'" -i $tempFilePath $finalFilePath 2>&1';` I think only double-quotes work on Windows. You need to quote `$tempFilePath $finalFilePath` if they might have spaces in them as well.

Comment: Then it says:
'".$this->ffmpegPath"' is not recognized as an internal or external command
i swear im about done with this language...

Comment: I added quotes around it with the combination of " and ' and it still spits out an error.

Comment: Variables are not expanded in single-quotes, so you have to switch them up and concatenate with `.`. Try the one in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, spaces in your command are used to separate arguments.  So if there are spaces in a path you need to quote the entire path with quotes so that the shell/processor knows they aren't separators but are one argument:

```
$cmd = $cmd = '"' . $this->ffmpegPath . '" -i $tempFilePath $finalFilePath 2>&1';
```

Which will result in a command something like this:

> "C:/xampp/htdocs/Thinksmart First Sprint/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -i C:/path/to/file1 C:/path/to/file2 2>&1

I think only double-quotes work on Windows. You need to quote `$tempFilePath` and  `$finalFilePath` if they might have spaces in them as well.

Comment: So i shouldn't use realpath? If i deploy this webapp, then im going to go in the server and configure the path of the file for each server i deploy it on? What if i use Linux servers? I don't mean to be rude, just want to ask, even though it sounds rude. It is literally only curiosity. As i said im kinda new to the whole video conversion and i rarely use these exec() commands on a global scope (outside of the root dir of the app)

Comment: I didn't say anything about not using `realpath`.  The `$thi->ffmpegPath` in the answer is from your `$this->ffmpegPath = realpath("ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe");`